# Transform one list of objects into another list

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, sorting, edit-distance

This is a theory question so I'm going to use pseudo code.

I have a list of objects that I need to transform into another list.

I implemented the Levenshtein algorithm, and that works just fine, but I need to preserve the objects, and not create new ones. I can brute force it but Id rather find a non O(n*m) way to do this.

[obj1,obj2,obj3] -> [obj1,obj4,obj5,obj2,obj6,obj3]

obj1,obj2,obj3 have to be the same object where the rest are newly created objects.

Anybody know a good algorithm for this?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer in pseudocode, because the answer depends on the features of your language. The answers for C++ and Java will be very different.

Comment: Are the objects in your question strings. What should the intermediate objects look like, are they the steps with edit distance 1?

Comment: No the objects are complex classes. All edit distances are 1. These are small lists of ordered user content. I'm doing this in C# and the lists are Lists of the class we made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pattern [flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), to do that you'll need to maintain created objects in the cache. Strings in java is a good example of this pattern.

Comment: I see how this would work. I end up going through each list only once. Ill implement it and get back. THANKS!! :)